# Fingerprint does not exist in the namespace 'Plugin' errors when I upgrade Visual Studio for Xcode 11 Previews to support iOS 13

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, ios13, xcode11

I am getting below errors when I upgrade Visual Studio for Xcode 11 Previews to support iOS 13.

1. Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Fingerprint' does not exist in the namespace 'Plugin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2. Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationRequestConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Below are the visual studio details
Visual Studio for Mac version 8.3
Mono Freamwork MDK : Mono 6.4.0
Xamarin.Android Version : 10.0.0.43
Xamarin.iOS Version : 13.2.0.42
Mac OS X : 10.14.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you have updated the version of Mono and IDE to newest .this issue often appears when the version of IDE or mono could match with iOS system.

Comment: You can also delete the folder `bin` and  `obj` in share project and iOS project. Then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have reinstall fresh Xamarin Studio 2019, so I have latest Xamarin studio with Mono framework. Also I tried with deleting bin and obj folder from all sub project but still getting same error.

Comment: You can add an issue on github https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint/issues.

Comment: Ok. Issues raised on github. Thanks @LucasZhang-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error.

1. Try to open .Net Runtimes.
   (Visual Studio > Preferences > Feature Switch > RUNTIME_SELECTOR√)
2. Mono version updates.

I hope you find this information helpful.